# How to get height of div with Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

My situation is as follows:
I need to look for the height of a DIV component to dynamically inform a child component of its size.

I'm trying to create a manual loading mode, but for some reason the height that is captured is less than the normal height.

It captures a size of 318px, but the correct height would be 393px.

The strangest thing of all, is that the moment I change the methods that look for the height, alternating between clientHeight and offsetHeight the autoload shows that the div gets the correct height, but if I update the page (F5) the height comes wrong and then forward it remains wrong.

Vue Code

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      height: 0,
      loading: false
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.height = this.$refs.infoBox.clientHeight;
  }
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="bg-white shadow-md rounded max-w-xs mx-auto" id="info-box" ref="infoBox">
  <div class="absolute max-w-xs w-full overflow-auto bg-white opacity-50" :style="{ height: height + 'px'}" v-if="loading"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

I hope I managed to explain the problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: hello diego, are you setting ```loading``` to false after setting  ```height``` in ```mounted``` ?

Comment: Hi Safi!
Thank you for your help

Not really, the definition for false is directly in the ```data``` function, but I added this configuration exactly thinking that the parent component might not have been assembled yet, so I added the ```v-if``` to try to guarantee it. I don't know if I used the logic correctly, but even if I remove this setting, the height keeps coming wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Whenever you're getting information from the DOM like this, it's advantageous to use `computed` properties:

```
  computed: {
    height () {
      return this.$refs.infoBox.clientHeight
    }
  }
```

This way Vue polls for changes to this variable and it'll be updated as the DOM updates. The problem with setting it once in `mounted` is that this obviously doesn't happen. Other then that you're grabbing it the right way. If it's a hardcoded height set in CSS you could also grab it out of the `style` object, but that's not a great idea.

Comment: Thanksss! I hadn't thought about using computers, it makes perfect sense! Thank you very much for your help, it worked as expected!

Comment: didn't work..I even tried using $nextTick and settimeout. Works on hot reload but not on page refresh